# How to avoid assignments of multiple arguments passed to constructor

Tags: c#, class

If i have a class in c# containing many variables that needs to be initialised in a constructor e.g.

```
public class AnyClass
{
    private int Var1; 
    private int Var2;
    ...
    private int varN;

    public AnyClass(int InVar1,int InVar2,...,InVarN)
    {
        Var1=InVar1;
        Var2=InVar2;
        ...
        VarN=InVarN;
        // 
        //Code
        //
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the intermediate variables InVar1, InVar2 etc in such a way that the arguments passed to the constructor are automatically mapped to the variables contained in the class.

Comment: I can't really say **no**, but I don't know of any way; the only option I can offer is the use of a parameterless constructor, but that would mean refactoring the class to make those properties instead.

Comment: Not *yet* but they may appear in C# 6 (See Primary Constructors). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908005/primary-constructors-in-c-sharp-vnext) which discusses them.

Comment: a small improvement is use this.var1 = var1, so you don't have to come up with a 2nd set of names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at present, [C# 6 may include it.](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated)

This is what is **may** look like

Before

```
public class Point {
    private int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

After

```
public class Point(private int x, private int y) {
}
```

If you don’t mind having properties with a public setter, you can use [Object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).  E.g.

```
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

Comment: Almost certainly will, I'd say. (At least in some form or another.)

Comment: I'd expect something like (without the backing fields): public class Point(public int x, public int y) {}

Comment: @JonSkeet, Hopefully someone will write a better blog post then the one I linked to showing what the current expectation is.....

Comment: @IanRingrose: My "first reactions" post shows some of it: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/04/04/c-6-first-reactions.aspx

Comment: Ok, I guess i'll just have to wait for c# 6 or use your suggestion about properties. Thanks