# How do I enable C# 6 for my existing project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

I have an existing project that I'd like to convert to use the new C# 6 features.

I've put this code into my application

```
public class Pairing(string left, string right)
{

}
```

But I get a CS1514 at the begin paren.

I'm running Visual Studio 2015

I've tried changing my language for the project (project properties -> build -> advanced -> language version -> C# 6.0), but that hasn't solved the problem.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: Primary constructors aren't valid in `C#6`, they were withdrawn from the spec: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820 - If the following compiles, then you are running `C#6` - `var blah = "there"; Console.WriteLine($"Hello {blah}");`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use primary constructors now. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908005/primary-constructors-in-c-sharp-vnext) regarding the same topic for more details.

Comment: Yes, I am agree with @Hernan Guzman Primary constructor feature has been removed you can check http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/c-sharp-6-modified-amp-removed-features